# Maven build fails with error LifecycleExecutionException and MojoExecutionException and java.lang.StackOverflowError

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, lombok, maven-compiler-plugin, corretto

mvn clean install gets success with java (jdk1.8.0_201) but fails to build with java (C:\Program Files (x86)\Amazon Corretto\jdk1.8.0_392). I am trying this with Corretto8 to deploy using aws codepipeline. The application rarely builds success with corretto8 (like gets success 1 in 30 times). Not sure why the stackOverflowError occurs.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.0:compile (default-compile) on project code-jip: Fatal error compiling: java.lang.StackOverflowError -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.0:compile (default-compile) on project code-jip: Fatal error compiling
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:972)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Fatal error compiling
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute (AbstractCompilerMojo.java:695)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute (CompilerMojo.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:972)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.CompilerException: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavaxToolsCompiler.compileInProcess (JavaxToolsCompiler.java:191)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavacCompiler.performCompile (JavacCompiler.java:170)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute (AbstractCompilerMojo.java:684)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute (CompilerMojo.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:972)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile (Main.java:553)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.doCall (JavacTaskImpl.java:129)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.call (JavacTaskImpl.java:138)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavaxToolsCompiler.compileInProcess (JavaxToolsCompiler.java:126)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavacCompiler.performCompile (JavacCompiler.java:170)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute (AbstractCompilerMojo.java:684)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute (CompilerMojo.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:972)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at lombok.core.AST.fieldsOf (AST.java:234)
    at lombok.javac.JavacAST.drill (JavacAST.java:421)
    at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildStatementOrExpression (JavacAST.java:387)
    at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildTree (JavacAST.java:196)
    at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildTree (JavacAST.java:1)
    at lombok.core.AST.buildWithField0 (AST.java:394)
    at lombok.core.AST.buildWithField (AST.java:292)
    at lombok.javac.JavacAST.drill (JavacAST.java:421)
    at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildStatementOrExpression (JavacAST.java:387)
    at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildTree (JavacAST.java:196)
    at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildTree (JavacAST.java:1)
    at lombok.core.AST.buildWithField0 (AST.java:394)
    at lombok.core.AST.buildWithField (AST.java:292)
    at lombok.javac.JavacAST.drill (JavacAST.java:421)
    at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildStatementOrExpression (JavacAST.java:387)
    at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildTree (JavacAST.java:196)
    at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildTree (JavacAST.java:1)
    at lombok.core.AST.buildWithField0 (AST.java:394)
    at lombok.core.AST.buildWithField (AST.java:292)
    at lombok.javac.JavacAST.drill (JavacAST.java:421)
    at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildStatementOrExpression (JavacAST.java:387)
    at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildTree (JavacAST.java:196)
    at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildTree (JavacAST.java:1)
    at lombok.core.AST.buildWithField0 (AST.java:394)
    at lombok.core.AST.buildWithField (AST.java:292)
    at lombok.javac.JavacAST.drill (JavacAST.java:421)
    at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildStatementOrExpression (JavacAST.java:387)
    at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildTree (JavacAST.java:196)
    at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildTree (JavacAST.java:1)
    at lombok.core.AST.buildWithField0 (AST.java:394)
    at lombok.core.AST.buildWithField (AST.java:292)
    at lombok.javac.JavacAST.drill (JavacAST.java:421)
    at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildStatementOrExpression (JavacAST.java:387)
    at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildTree (JavacAST.java:196)
    at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildTree (JavacAST.java:1)
    at lombok.core.AST.buildWithField0 (AST.java:394)
    at lombok.core.AST.buildWithField (AST.java:292)
    at lombok.javac.JavacAST.drill (JavacAST.java:421)
    at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildStatementOrExpression (JavacAST.java:387)
    at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildTree (JavacAST.java:196)
    at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildTree (JavacAST.java:1)
    at lombok.core.AST.buildWithField0 (AST.java:394)
    at lombok.core.AST.buildWithField (AST.java:292)
    at lombok.javac.JavacAST.drill (JavacAST.java:421)
    at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildStatementOrExpression (JavacAST.java:387)
    at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildTree (JavacAST.java:196)
    at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildTree (JavacAST.java:1)
    at lombok.core.AST.buildWithField0 (AST.java:394)
    at lombok.core.AST.buildWithField (AST.java:292)
    at lombok.javac.JavacAST.drill (JavacAST.java:421)
    at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildStatementOrExpression (JavacAST.java:387)
    at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildTree (JavacAST.java:196)
    at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildTree (JavacAST.java:1)
    at lombok.core.AST.buildWithField0 (AST.java:394)
    at lombok.core.AST.buildWithField (AST.java:292)
    at lombok.javac.JavacAST.drill (JavacAST.java:421)
    at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildStatementOrExpression (JavacAST.java:387)
    at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildTree (JavacAST.java:196)
    at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildTree (JavacAST.java:1)
    at lombok.core.AST.buildWithField0 (AST.java:394)
    at lombok.core.AST.buildWithField (AST.java:292)
    at lombok.javac.JavacAST.drill (JavacAST.java:421)
    at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildStatementOrExpression (JavacAST.java:387)
    at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildTree (JavacAST.java:196)
    at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildTree (JavacAST.java:1)
    at lombok.core.AST.buildWithField0 (AST.java:394)
    at lombok.core.AST.buildWithField (AST.java:292)
    at lombok.javac.JavacAST.drill (JavacAST.java:421)
    at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildStatementOrExpression (JavacAST.java:387)
    at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildTree (JavacAST.java:196)
    at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildTree (JavacAST.java:1)
    at lombok.core.AST.buildWithField0 (AST.java:394)
    at lombok.core.AST.buildWithField (AST.java:292)
    at lombok.javac.JavacAST.drill (JavacAST.java:421)
    at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildStatementOrExpression (JavacAST.java:387)
    at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildTree (JavacAST.java:196)
    at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildTree (JavacAST.java:1)
    at lombok.core.AST.buildWithField0 (AST.java:394)
    at lombok.core.AST.buildWithField (AST.java:292)
    at lombok.javac.JavacAST.drill (JavacAST.java:421)
    at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildStatementOrExpression (JavacAST.java:387)
    at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildTree (JavacAST.java:196)
    at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildTree (JavacAST.java:1)
    at lombok.core.AST.buildWithField0 (AST.java:394)
    at lombok.core.AST.buildWithField (AST.java:292)
    at lombok.javac.JavacAST.drill (JavacAST.java:421)
    at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildStatementOrExpression (JavacAST.java:387)
    at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildTree (JavacAST.java:196)
    at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildTree (JavacAST.java:1)
    at lombok.core.AST.buildWithField0 (AST.java:394)
    at lombok.core.AST.buildWithField (AST.java:292)
    at lombok.javac.JavacAST.drill (JavacAST.java:421)
```

I have tried updating the source and target with different versions in pom. But not succeeded.

```
<plugins>
 <plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.0</version>
  <configuration>
   <source>1.8</source>
   <target>1.8</target>
  </configuration>
 </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Q1. The project doesn't have lombok configured. Is corretto8 internally uses lombok? If so how to exclude it while compiling?

Q2. I have seen some post (but doesn't give me a solution) that it may cause due to circular dependency classes. If that's the case is there any tool i can use to figure out the classes to refactor it?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have Lombok included, as it definitifly looks like it you have. You could also try to use a newer version of the compiler plugin 3.11.0 is the latest you are still oin 3.0.

Comment: You are right @M.Deinum. The third party dependency downloads the lombok internally. If i exclude the lombok, then the build gets success. But looks like lombok is needed internally. I have tried with 3.11.0. But still no luck on this.

Comment: If the build succeeds without lombok doesn't that imply it works without lombok? Lombok is a processor that gets used during compilation to produce/modify bytecode.